# Alignment of table entries: the case of negative numbers

Tags: tables, align

Assume that we have a table that has positive and negative entries.

My question is simple: how can we have the number alignment to start from the actual number and not the negative (-) symbol?

Let me introduce a simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttablex, booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{} } \toprule
& a & b & c \\ \midrule
\textit{something} &&& \\ \midrule
something & -0.888 & 0.888 & 0.888 \\
something & 0.888** & 0.888* & 0.888*** \\
something & -0.888*** & -0.888*** & -0.888*** \\
something & 0.888* & 0.037 & 0.888 \\ \midrule
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
} 
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `dcolumn` package to achieve alignment on the decimal marker. To determine the number of "digits" to show before and after the decimal marker, include objects such as minus signs and asterisks. For the current example, a column specification of `d{2.6}` works ver well.

I've further modified your code to (a) omit loading all unneeded packages, (b) use a `\centering` instruction *inside* the `table` environment, and (c) skip encasing the `\footnotesize` directive in a pair of curly braces since the scope of the directive ends with the `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}  % define "d" column type
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *3{d{2.6}} @{} } \toprule
& \mc{a} & \mc{b} & \mc{c} \\ \midrule
\textit{something}  \\ \midrule
something & -0.888    &  0.888    &  0.888    \\
something &  0.888*** &  0.888*   &  0.888*** \\
something & -0.888*** & -0.888*** & -0.888*** \\
something & 0.888* & 0.037 & 0.888 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum*: Here's what the same table looks like when using the `beamer` instead of the `article` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}  % define "d" column type
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *3{d{2.6}} @{} } \toprule
& \mc{a} & \mc{b} & \mc{c} \\ \midrule
\textit{something}  \\ \midrule
something & -0.888    &  0.888    &  0.888    \\
something &  0.888*** &  0.888*   &  0.888*** \\
something & -0.888*** & -0.888*** & -0.888*** \\
something &  0.888*   & 0.037     &  0.888 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico thanks. I followed your way also. I am preparing a beamer presentation now. However, I see that this method changes the font in the entries (only there). I guess it makes it Times New Roman. Why is that?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis - The font shown in the screenshot is Computer Modern, the system default. Note that material in a `d` column is set in math mode. Do you maybe have different fonts for text and math mode?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis - I've provided an addendum to show what the table would like like when using the `beamer` instead of the `article` document class.

Comment: I use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. I checked it  and without it all fonts are the same

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to typeset the columns. The options to `\sisetup` set the width of the columns appropriately (one digit to the left, three to the right of the decimal point, plus space for the sign). Note that I removed several of the unnecessary packages from this MWE, and removed the unnecessary `center` environment, changing it to the `\centering` command. Also note the curly braces `{}` around the `a`, `b`, and `c` column headers to ensure they are set as text and not parsed by `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3, table-space-text-post={***}}

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} lSSS @{} } \toprule
& {a} & {b} & {c} \\ \midrule
\textit{something} &&& \\ \midrule
something & -0.888 & 0.888 & 0.888 \\
something & 0.888** & 0.888* & 0.888*** \\
something & -0.888*** & -0.888*** & -0.888*** \\
something & 0.888* & 0.037 & 0.888 \\ \midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you encase a couple of the asterisk groups in curly braces?

Comment: Oh! That was part of my testing for the spacing (before I saw the `table-space-text-post` key) that I forgot to take out! Thanks for the note

Answer (score 4):

I did two things:  I replace the "-" signs with `\phanm` which I define; and I increased `\tabcolsep` a little to leave some space for the phantoms.

By making the minuses into `\llap`ed characters, one avoids the (what I find) ugly appearance of having the "a", "b", and "c" aligned with the minuses.

Note: your original solution did not have the minuses in math mode.

EDITED to take Mico's good advice, which I had glossed over in the OP's MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttablex, booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\def\phanm{\llap{$-$}}
\tabcolsep=\dimexpr\tabcolsep+1ex\relax
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{} } \toprule
& a & b & c \\ \midrule
\textit{something} &&& \\ \midrule
something & \phanm0.888 & 0.888 & 0.888 \\
something & 0.888** & 0.888* & 0.888*** \\
something & \phanm0.888*** & \phanm0.888*** & \phanm0.888*** \\
something & 0.888* & 0.037 & 0.888 \\ \midrule
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Done.  Thx.

Answer (score 4):

You have at least three options:

1. Use a `l`eft-aligned column and introduce a `\phantom{-}` for positive numbers:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}}
     \toprule
     & a & b & c \\
     \midrule
     \textit{something} &&& \\
     \midrule
     something & $-0.888$ & $\phantom{-}0.888$ & $\phantom{-}0.888$ \\
     something & $\phantom{-}0.888^{\text{**}}$ & $\phantom{-}0.888^{\text{*}}$ & $\phantom{-}0.888^{\text{***}}$ \\
     something & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ \\
     something & $\phantom{-}0.888^{\text{*}}$ & $\phantom{-}0.037$ & $\phantom{-}0.888$ \\
     \bottomrule 
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use a `r`ight-aligned column and introduce a `\phantom` for numbers not having any "adjustments":

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{@{} rrrr @{}}
     \toprule
     & a & b & c \\
     \midrule
     \textit{something} &&& \\
     \midrule
     something & $-0.888\phantom{{}^{\text{***}}}$ & $0.888\phantom{{}^{\text{***}}}$ & $0.888\phantom{{}^{\text{***}}}$ \\
     something & $0.888^{\text{**\phantom{*}}}$ & $0.888^{\text{*\phantom{**}}}$ & $0.888^{\text{***}}$ \\
     something & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ & $-0.888^{\text{***}}$ \\
     something & $0.888^{\text{*\phantom{**}}}$ & $0.037\phantom{{}^{\text{***}}}$ & $0.888\phantom{{}^{\text{***}}}$ \\
     \bottomrule 
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209020/5764).

Comment: solution #1 doesn't require using another package and is a clean hack. Great answer!