# Combining ThreePartTable, longtable and tabularx preserving table entries alignment

Tags: longtable, tabularx, siunitx, threeparttable

This question is a follow up of [Alignment of table entries (part 2): negative numbers and table panels with different units of measurement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354932/alignment-of-table-entries-part-2-negative-numbers-and-table-panels-with-diff/354961?noredirect=1#comment874598_354961), from which I use the code of one of the answers to create the following working example.

My aim is to use `ThreePartTable` to allow for the possiblity that the table spans across pages and use the flexible `TableNotes` environemnt.
The example below additionally uses `tabularx` to allow for flexible panels, each with different `table-format` settings from the `siunitx` package.
So if possible I would like to keep using this solution.

Normally, I would "embed" `longtable` into a `ThreePartTable` environment, define appropriate `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot` and include notes with `\insertTableNotes`. In this case I tried to create these breakpoints in the table, but with no success due to the two `tabularx` environments.
Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,longtable}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.7cm,vmargin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-2em}#1}  % for indentation
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\sisetup{group-separator={,} , group-four-digits=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}c@{}}
\caption {Example table} \label{tab:table_balance_AvsH}\\
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{ @{\hspace*{\leftmargin}} % first 'tabularx'
    l *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
    S[table-format=-1.2] S[table-format=2.2]
    *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 2} \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} \\
    & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\  
    \midrule
    \rowgroup{\textit{Panel A: Outcome 1 (USD)\phantom{Th.~}}} 
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$  & 8.76 & 9.28 & -0.52 & 10.71 & 6.93 & 3.78 \\
    $t - 4$  & 9.07 & 9.17 & -0.10 & 9.07 & 6.93  & 2.14 \\
    $t - 3$  & 9.34 & 8.36 & 0.97  & 9.36 & 7.27  & 2.09 \\
    $t - 2$  & 9.33 & 8.46 & 0.87  & 9.43 & 8.07  & 1.36 \\
    $t - 1$  & 9.40 & 9.07 & 0.33  & 8.87 & 8.33  & 0.53 \\
    \addlinespace
\end{tabularx}\\

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{ @{\hspace*{\leftmargin}} % second 'tabularx'
    l S[table-format=-3.0] S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=-4.0,table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{*}]
      *{2}{S[table-format=4.0]}
      S[table-format=-3.0,table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{*}]}      
    \rowgroup{\textit{Panel B: Outcome 2 (Th.\ USD)}} 
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$  &  456 & 650 &  -194\textsuperscript{*} & 1007 &  656  & 352 \\
    $t - 4$  &  490 & 650 &  -160\textsuperscript{*} & 1055 &  619  & 436\textsuperscript{*} \\
    $t - 3$  & -383 & 625 & -1008     & 1060 &  663  & 398 \\
    $t - 2$  & -467 & 653 & -1120     & 1120 &  877  & 242 \\
    $t - 1$  &  666 & 746 &   -80     & 1117 & 1020  &  97  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two consecutive  `tabularx` environments, which can break across pages thanks to the `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of  `longtable` to `tabularx`. These environments are nested in a `ThreePartTable` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, siunitx, threeparttablex, caption}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.7cm,vmargin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-2em}#1} % for indentation
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\sisetup{group-separator={,} , group-four-digits=true}
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}


\vspace*{15cm}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] \label{tn:a}Lalala…
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{ @{\hspace*{\leftmargin}} % first 'tabularx'
    l *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
    S[table-format=-1.2] S[table-format=2.2]
    *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
\caption{Example table} \label{tab:table_balance_AvsH}\\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 2} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} \\
    & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Period 2} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} & {Group 1} & {Group 2} & {Diff.} \\
    & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
\midrule\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    \rowgroup{\textit{Panel A: Outcome 1 (USD)\phantom{Th.~}}}
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$\tnote{a} & 8.76 & 9.28 & -0.52 & 10.71 & 6.93 & 3.78\\
    $t - 4$ & 9.07 & 9.17 & -0.10 & 9.07 & 6.93 & 2.14 \\
    $t - 3$ & 9.34 & 8.36 & 0.97 & 9.36 & 7.27 & 2.09 \\
    $t - 2$ & 9.33 & 8.46 & 0.87 & 9.43 & 8.07 & 1.36 \\
    $t - 1$ & 9.40 & 9.07 & 0.33 & 8.87 & 8.33 & 0.53 \\
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$ & 8.76 & 9.28 & -0.52 & 10.71 & 6.93 & 3.78 \\
    $t - 4$ & 9.07 & 9.17 & -0.10 & 9.07 & 6.93 & 2.14 \\
    $t - 3$ & 9.34 & 8.36 & 0.97 & 9.36 & 7.27 & 2.09 \\
    $t - 2$ & 9.33 & 8.46 & 0.87 & 9.43 & 8.07 & 1.36 \\
    $t - 1$ & 9.40 & 9.07 & 0.33 & 8.87 & 8.33 & 0.53 \\
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$ & 8.76 & 9.28 & -0.52 & 10.71 & 6.93 & 3.78 \\
    $t - 4$ & 9.07 & 9.17 & -0.10 & 9.07 & 6.93 & 2.14 \\
    $t - 3$ & 9.34 & 8.36 & 0.97 & 9.36 & 7.27 & 2.09 \\
    $t - 2$ & 9.33 & 8.46 & 0.87 & 9.43 & 8.07 & 1.36 \\
    $t - 1$ & 9.40 & 9.07 & 0.33 & 8.87 & 8.33 & 0.53 \\
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
    $t - 5$ & 8.76 & 9.28 & -0.52 & 10.71 & 6.93 & 3.78 \\
    $t - 4$ & 9.07 & 9.17 & -0.10 & 9.07 & 6.93 & 2.14 \\
    $t - 3$ & 9.34 & 8.36 & 0.97 & 9.36 & 7.27 & 2.09 \\
    $t - 2$ & 9.33 & 8.46 & 0.87 & 9.43 & 8.07 & 1.36 \\
    $t - 1$ & 9.40 & 9.07 & 0.33 & 8.87 & 8.33 & 0.53
\\
\end{tabularx}%\\
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{ @{\hspace*{\leftmargin}} % second 'tabularx'
    l S[table-format=-3.0] S[table-format=3.0]
      S[table-format=-4.0,table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{*}]
      *{2}{S[table-format=4.0]}
      S[table-format=-3.0,table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{*}]}
    \rowgroup{\textit{Panel B: Outcome 2 (Th.\ USD)}}
    & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} \\
\endhead
\midrule\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    $t - 5$ & 456 & 650 & -194\textsuperscript{*} & 1007 & 656 & 352 \\
    $t - 4$ & 490 & 650 & -160\textsuperscript{*} & 1055 & 619 & 436\textsuperscript{*} \\
    $t - 3$ & -383 & 625 & -1008 & 1060 & 663 & 398 \\
    $t - 2$ & -467 & 653 & -1120 & 1120 & 877 & 242 \\
    $t - 1$ & 666 & 746 & -80 & 1117 & 1020 & 97 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ Bernard Hi, I have a related problem for correctly numbering the tables in the text. To keep things clear I opened a different question here: [Correcting labels numbering of ThreePartTable containing multiple tabularx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361737/correcting-labels-numbering-of-threeparttable-containing-multiple-tabularx)